# Unable to access value from checkbutton tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a Checkbutton in tkinter, but when I access the checked value, it returns nothing:

```
self.inttype = IntVar()
self.setrandom = Checkbutton(self.userpanel, text='Random', variable=self.inttype)
self.setrandom.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=EW)
```

Here I am printing value:

```
print('Value : ', self.inttype.get())
```

The output is:

```
Value:
```

Is there any other method to get the value from the checkbutton?

Comment: Have you called the main windows mainloop() before doing print('Value : ', self.inttype.get())?

Comment: yes, i have called actually i have applied same method in my previous code there is no problem but this time it shows nothing

Comment: Could you please post a full working example (possibly stripped down to the essential parts) of your code?

Comment: Here this is my working code :

   self.val = StringVar()  

   self.productionval = Radiobutton(self.userscreenpanel, text='Production', value='p', variable=self.val, **entryset)  

        self.productionval.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky=W)  

        self.reproductionval = Radiobutton(self.userscreenpanel, text='Reproduction', value='r', variable=self.val, **entryset)  
        self.reproductionval.grid(row=7, column=2, sticky=W)

value = self.val.get()

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself in a wrong way. What I wanted you to post is the code to reproduce your problem, something that others can copy paste and run without having to guess parts of the code. Try to make it as small as possible while still reproducing the problem you encounter.

Comment: ok let me see if i could paste my complete code here

Comment: Please don't paste your full code, paste an MCVE (http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And don't paste it in a comment, please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.inttype = IntVar()
self.setrandom = Checkbutton(self.userpanel, text='Random', variable=self.inttype, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
self.setrandom.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=EW)
```

Can you see what changes I made? I've just added an argument `onvalue`. Only defining the variable is not enough. You have to set a value that it must take when it is selected.

Comment: I have checked this method also but it takes 0 value bydefault

Comment: Check when are you printing the value. If it is before you change the check mark then it would show an empty string. Try setting a default value to it.

Comment: I have printed this value after the checkbutton is checked but stills value is 0

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you use `tk.IntVar()` for a checkbutton when you are not using "onvalue" / "offvalue" Parameters at Checkbutton creation?

If you just want to see `true` / `false` values for your states use `tk.BooleanVar()`.

Please note that default values of checkbuttons are `True` / `False`.

If you use an `tk.IntVar()` you will not see anything as long as you are not specifying `onvalue` / `offvalue`.

See working code attached.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

checked = tk.BooleanVar()
i_checked = tk.IntVar()
s_checked = tk.StringVar()
s_checked.set("off")

def cb_checked(event=None):
    global checked
    print("Test Checkbutton Value: {}".format(checked.get()))

def cb_i_checked(event=None):
    global i_checked
    print("Integer Checkbutton Value: {}".format(i_checked.get()))

def cb_s_checked(event=None):
    global s_checked
    print("String Checkbutton Value: {}".format(s_checked.get()))

chkbtn_test = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Test", variable=checked, command=cb_checked)
chkbtn_test.grid(row=0)

chkbtn_int = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Integer", variable=i_checked, onvalue=2, offvalue=-2, command=cb_i_checked)
chkbtn_int.grid(row=1)

chkbtn_string = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="String", variable=s_checked, onvalue="on", offvalue="off", command=cb_s_checked)
chkbtn_string.grid(row=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Output added beyond.

[image: Output of above code]

Comment: I have used this same method but value in empty when checked. Using BooleanVar() I am getting False if checked or not Checkbutton